# JQuery Selecting closest parent a:link

Tags: jquery, parent-child, closest, toggleclass

I'm trying to toggle a CSS class for the closest parent `a:link` in a navigation menu based on the child sub-menu being hovered.  I can get it to work for the closest parent `<li>` tag, but not the `a:link` inside which I want this event to occur for.

The HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">First Parent</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">First Child</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Second Child</a></li>
     </ul></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second Parent</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">First Child</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Second Child</a></li>
     </ul></li>
</ul>
```

So, the function I have written to select the parent `<li>` which is working is :

```
$("ul.sub-menu").hover(function(){
        $(this).closest("li").toggleClass("parenthovered");
});
```

but how can I get this class to toggle for the `a:link` of the parent in `ul.menu li`?  Something like:

```
$("ul.sub-menu").hover(function(){
        $(this).closest("li a").toggleClass("parenthovered");
});
```

but that of course does not work, I'm just not sure what syntax I need to change.

Many thanks SO.

Comment: Try `.closest("li").find('a')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("ul.sub-menu").hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings('a').toggleClass("parenthovered");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2KhnX/9/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2KhnX/8/ - that's what I'm getting.  The sub-menu is within it's parent `<li></li>` tag, like you suggested.

Comment: @RCNeil in your fiddle you don't include jQuery 1.7.2. check that and include and then text..I give ans with you HTML

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2KhnX/11/ - I've included all of the CSS involved in the menu to hopefully provide a better scope.  I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @RCNeil include jquery library in your fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2KhnX/15/ - with the JQuery library.  Your demo works, so it's clearly something wrong on my end.  Perhaps with my CSS.  At least I have a solid example to go off of.  Thank you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10397/discussion-between-rcneil-and-thecodeparadox)

Comment: turns out it was happening because the specificity of the "new" CSS class did not override the old CSS properties.  It wasn't specific enough.  Thank you again for your help. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285985/jquery-sibling-selector-not-appending-class-because-of-css[/link]

Answer (score 2):

You can always use:

```
    $("ul.sub-menu").hover(function(){
            $("a", $(this).closest("li")).toggleClass("parenthovered");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `find` the nested `<a>` inside of the `<li>` you've already got.

```
$("ul.sub-menu").hover(function() {
  $(this).closest("li").find("a").toggleClass("parenthovered");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use find method to get the a tag inside the tag.

```
$("ul.sub-menu").hover(function(){
        $(this).closest("li").find("a").toggleClass("parenthovered");
});
```