# JQuery Sibling Selector not Appending Class because of CSS

Tags: css, jquery-selectors, toggleclass

I have a menu with sub-menu child navigation as well, and I'm trying to append a class to the parent of the children based on the hovering of the children's `<ul>` container.

This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/2KhnX/15/

but as you can see, the class never gets appended.  If I strip most of the CSS from the HTML, but leave the class I'd like appended, it works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/2KhnX/21/

Which leaves me to believe that the CSS is conflicting or ruining the event that the JQuery is attempting to carry out.  My guess would be because I'm using the `parent > child` rules of CSS, or perhaps because `.sub-menu` has an initial property of `display:none`.  I'm not sure, I just know that the CSS is messing this up, or that I'm not using the appropriate selector *because* of the CSS.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, for I am lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the offending css:

```
ul.menu li a:link, ul.menu li a:visited {
        background: url('images/alink.jpg') top center repeat-x;
}
.parenthovered {
    /* stuff */
}
```

Those first selectors have a higher [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) than the .parenthovered selector, and thus are taking precedence. You can address this in a few ways; one way is to be less specific on the first set of selectors, and more specific on the second selector:

```
a:link, a:visited {
        background: url('images/alink.jpg') top center repeat-x;
}

.menu a.parenthovered {
    /* stuff */
}
```

Of course, you'll have to choose selectors that make sense for the rest of your page...

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pabo/NR4yB/1/

Also, removing this line works too:

```
background: url('images/alink.jpg') top center repeat-x;
```

Comment: wow... thanks!  Very in-dept explanation as well!  I couldn't have asked for a better answer.